# How to setup ZF2 on live server

Tags: .htaccess, installation, zend-framework2

I have a question, where should I put framework folders on live server? That's my first application in Zend Framework 2. On localhost everything seems to work fine, I wanted test it on live server and I got confused.

```
 home
   home/username
     home/username/public_html
```

I put everything in public_html with copied .htaccess from Zend's public folder. So my structure looks like this:

```
 home/
   home/username/
     home/username/public_html/
       config/
       data/
       module/
       public/
       vendor/
       .htaccess
       init_autoloader.php
```

But I can't access my application in `www.mydomain.com/` I have to use `www.mydomain.com/public`
I think the problem is with .htaccess, so here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

I tried add `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [NC,L]` but it didn't change anything.
Is it a proper structure of application on live server?
Where should I keep vendor folder?

Answer (score 0):

I usually clone my application to /home/username/application and symlink /home/username/public_html to application/public

Your location of the vendor folder is fine!